# c# adding indentation or spaces to beginning of string

Tags: c#, string, datatable

just as a disclaimer, I'm relatively new to c# (6 months) as I started using it at a new job that required it and I'm the only developer in the office.

So I've been working on automating variable sized documents using tables with DocumentFormat.OpenXML.Wordprocessing and I've been hitting a snag with indentation at the start strings that I put into the table cells where each paragraph exists.
I add strings to different rows of a DataTable that I later turn into individual Runs within Paragraphs inside TableCells of a table that I insert into my document.

I'll start strings with a variable "spacing"

```
var spacing = " ".PadLeft(10);
```

Then I'll use it in two different scenarios:

```
DataTable.Rows.Add(spacing +"start of paragraph");
DataTable.Rows.Add("start" + spacing + "of paragraph");
```

and the two outputs are:

> start of paragraph
>   start__________of paragraph

(the underscores are spaces)
while the outputs i want are

> __________start of paragraph
>   start__________of paragraph

Clearly "spacing" is being read properly when in between other strings but it is not being read at all at the beginning of the string

Does anyone know how to remedy this? I've tried indenting at the paragraph level when i convert the Datatable to Table() to no avail and I'm truly desperate on how to force c# to do this.

Comment: If nothing else you could try putting an invisible character before the empty spaces, e.g. a period in a tiny font set to the background color.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue. There must be something else than what you have provided that is the problem. Here is the code I used to try to reproduce it. `var dt = new DataTable(); dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()); var spacing = " ".PadLeft(10); dt.Rows.Add(spacing + "start of paragraph"); dt.Rows.Add("start" + spacing + "of paragraph"); foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) Console.WriteLine(row[0]);` Stackoverflow won't let me type many whitespace characters in a row but the console shows many spaces for the first row.

Comment: Maybe the way you display the results is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are not calling the `.Trim()` method when you display the values of the `DataTable` rows.  `Trim()` removes spaces on the beginning and end of a `string`, but not if whitespace only appears in the middle.

For instance, if I write the code in **Listing 1**, I'll get what you state is the undesired text, above, as output:

```
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace MyConsoleApp
{
  public static class Program
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
      var dt = new DataTable(); 
      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()); 
      var spacing = " ".PadLeft(10); 
      dt.Rows.Add(spacing + "start of paragraph"); 
      dt.Rows.Add("start" + spacing + "of paragraph"); 
      
      for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(DataRowToString(dt.Rows[i]).Trim());
      }
    }

    private static string DataRowToString(DataRow row)
    {
      var result = string.Empty;
      
      try
      {         
        if (row == null) return result;
        
        result = row.ToString();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.Message}");
        
        result = string.Empty;
      }
      
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

**Listing 1.**  Code of 'MyConsoleApp' that `.Trim()`s each output line before writing it to the screen.

Otherwise, if I leave off the `.Trim()` call, then I get your desired output.  For example, this is how the correct version of my example would look:

```
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace MyConsoleApp
{
  public static class Program
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
      var dt = new DataTable(); 
      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()); 
      var spacing = " ".PadLeft(10); 
      dt.Rows.Add(spacing + "start of paragraph"); 
      dt.Rows.Add("start" + spacing + "of paragraph"); 
      
      for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(DataRowToString(dt.Rows[i]));
      }
    }

    private static string DataRowToString(DataRow row)
    {
      var result = string.Empty;
      
      try
      {         
        if (row == null) return result;
        
        result = row.ToString();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.Message}");
        
        result = string.Empty;
      }
      
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

**Listing 2.** Code without the call to `String.Trim()`.

Execute the code in **Listing 2** and you should obtain the desired output.

**MORAL OF THE STORY**

Check your display code for `.Trim()` calls.

[Documentation on the Trim method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-8.0)